# How to exactly use PHP strtotime with 'this monday' combined with a time?

Tags: php, strtotime

I have a problem with the PHP function `strtotime` in which we try to get the date of a certain next day+time.

What I want is to get the next date+time of every next `'monday 20:00H'`. (we use a 24H time format)

```
$next_moment = strtotime('this monday 20:00');
```

The above code does exactly what we want BUT if it's for example monday the 10th,
after 20:00H it still says that the next occurence is Monday the 10th 20:00.

I have to wait until AFTER monday 24:00H, which is the same as Tuesday 00:00H. After that time, the result is correct again and displaying monday 17th 20:00H.

Please help to correct this.

Comment: just out of curiosity, does "next monday 20:00" works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$next_valid_date_time = strtotime('this Monday 20:00');

if(time() > $next_valid_date_time) {
    $next_valid_date_time = strtotime('Monday next week 20:00');
} 

echo date('Y-m-d H:i', $next_valid_date_time);
```

Comment: Thanks guys. The time comparison did the trick! Thank you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the current timestamp is larger than target timestamp.

```
$next_moment = ( time() > strtotime( "Monday 20:00" ) ? strtotime( "next Monday 20:00" ) : strtotime( "Monday 20:00" ) );
echo ( date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $next_moment ) );
```

Change the date and time for testing.

[PHP Relative Formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

Comment: Thanks guys. The time comparison did the trick! Thank you ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$next_moment = strtotime('this Monday 20:00');

if(time() > $next_moment) {
    $next_moment = strtotime('Monday next week 20:00');
} 

echo date('c',$next_moment);
```

Comment: Thanks guys. The time comparison did the trick! Thank you ;-)